# How to concat two javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I seem to have trouble to concat two javascript arrays. Here is the code:

```
console.log("\n\n");
a = [[1,2]];
b = [[1,2,3]];
console.table(a);
console.table(b);
a.concat(b);
console.table(a);
```

in which I create two arrays 'a' and 'b' (with elements being arrays as well, but who cares), with the goal of adding the single element of 'b' (the array `[1,2,3]` to the array 'a'. I expect 'b' to have two elements now (the array `[1,2]` and the array `[1,2,3]`, but it does not look so. I get the output as follows:

[image]

I expected the last output of `console.table` to have two rows with the content

```
0   1   2
1   1   2   3
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulate an exisiting array `a.concat(b)` returns a new one.

you should try:

```
var c = a.concat(b)
console.table(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.concat` doesn't mutate the original array, you have to re-assign:

```
a = a.concat(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

`concat()` does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays. you will have to assign it to some variable.

```js
console.log("\n\n");
a = [[1,2]];
b = [[1,2,3]];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(a.concat(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 you can use the spread operator to get the desired result:

```
console.log("\n\n");
a = [[1,2]];
b = [[1,2,3]];
console.table(a);
console.table(b);
c = [...a, ...b];
console.table(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

If arrays `a` and `b` have one element each then this will give you the answer

```
var c = a[0].concat(b[0]);
```

otherwise you would have to use a map or easily do it in ES6 with ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are avoiding the reassignment, you could use `Array.push.apply()`:

```js
var a = [[1,2]],
    b = [[1,2,3]];

a.push.apply(a,b);

console.log(a);
```

***Note:*** This was offered for completeness, my opinion would be to use `concat` assign as it's easier for me to understand what is occurring.